# How to balance the redox reaction between bismuth(III) sulfide and nitrate anion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, stoichiometry

I have to solve the following redox reaction which occurs in an acidic environment, using the **half-equation method**.

$$\ce {Bi2S3_{(s)} + NO3-_{(aq)} -> BiO3-_{(aq)} + SO4^2-_{(aq)} + NO_{(g)}}$$

There seems to be a lot elements that change their oxidation numbers, except for oxygen:

- $\ce{Bi}$ from $\ce{+III}$ to $\ce{+V}$
- $\ce{S}$ from $\ce{-II}$ to $\ce{+VI}$
- $\ce{N}$ from $\ce{+V}$ to $\ce{+II}$

What should I begin with? How would one go about grouping three redox pairs?

Comment: If possible, please try not to use MathJax in titles on Chemistry.SE. Please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149) for more details.

Comment: There might not be a unique answer. Multiple redoxes are difficult because you cannot necessarily add two reduction potentials or two oxidation potentials...

Comment: N is from +5, not +3.

Answer (score 3):

While in general a reaction involving three independent redox pairs may not have unique coefficients, this particular one contains one coupled oxidation half-reaction and one regular reduction half-reaction.

The key is to note that both elements in $\ce{Bi2S3}$ are oxidized, and hence we have a stoichiometric relationship between the two oxidation half-reactions. This suggests we write the oxidation half-reaction as follows: $$\ce{18H2O + Bi2S3 -> 2BiO3- + 3SO4^{2-} + 36H+ + 28e-,}$$ and we can proceed with the usual algorithm for balancing half-reactions.